# Exhausting a prolog tree without prompting the user, and without returning false. Is it possible?

Tags: prolog

I would like to exhaust a Prolog "tree" without prompting the user to press ; (to see every option).

I do this with the following code:

```
testLocation(room1).

testItem(number,room1).
testItem(number2,room1).
testItem(number3,room1).

test2(Location) :- testItem(X,Location), write(X), nl, fail.
```

The output is:

```
?- test2(room1).

number
number2
number3
false.
```

Is there anyway to have it not print false at the end? I have a feeling you might be able to do it with cuts. Or perhaps me using fail to write everything at once isn't the write solution.

Any Ideas?

Comment: try `test2(Location) :- testItem(X,Location), write(X), nl, fail ; true.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easier way should be

```
test2(Location) :- forall(testItem(X, Location), writeln(X)).
```

see the interesting [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2 documentation page for details.
If you need more than one callable, you can use conjunction for both Cond and Action parts: a dummy example

```
... forall((true, testItem(X, Location)), (write(X), nl)) ...
```

Comment: Not necessarily "easier" but I think it's better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
test2(Location) :-
  testItem(X,Location),
  write(X),nl,
  fail.
test2(_).
```

Which will always succeed.

You can do something like this:

```
test2(L,R) :-
  findall(X,testItem(X,L),R)
  .
```

But what's wrong with "failure": that just means the solution set is exhausted.

Comment: In your case an accidental failure of testItem/2 remains undetected.